# Объекты в Json.

Tags: json, php, синтаксический-анализ

Есть `json` ответ:

```
{
    response: {
        items: [
            {
                type: "post",
                post_id: 1,
                text: "This is text one!"
            }
            {
                type: "post",
                post_id: 2,
                text: "This is text two!"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Как средствами `php` вывести все `объекты` (объекты?) из списка `items`?

По одному `(?)`объекту возвращаю. Например `text`:

```
echo $json[response][items][0][text];
```

Не пойму как вывести все `items`. И правильно сформулировать это Гуглу — тоже не получается. :(

А ещё их (объекты) нужно оформить средствами html :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода

```
<?php
    $json = '{ "response": {"items": [{"type": "post", "post_id": 1, "text": "This is text one!"},{"type": "post", "post_id": 2, "text": "This is text two!"}]}}';

    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($data["response"]["items"] as $item) {
        echo "<div>".$item["post_id"]." - ".$item["text"]."</div>";
    }
?>
```

Результат:

```
<div>1 - This is text one!</div><div>2 - This is text two!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_encode($json, true);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: По-моему вы не поняли суть вопроса. :(

Comment: @stasQa, `json_encode` вернет строку. Тут нужен `json_decode` (по синтаксису параметров вы похоже его и имели в виду).